# Encontrar index de maior elemento da lista

Tags: python, lista, tupla

Estou montando um código que cria uma lista com 3 itens de compra, e dentro dessa lista algumas tuples com os nomes dos produtos e os respectivos preços. Eu quero encontrar o menor preço e exibir, junto com o nome do produto. Deve ser algum ajuste bobo, mas não consegui identificar como posso linkar o menor preço ao nome do produto correspondente. Podem ajudar?

```
    lista_de_compras = [
    (('Batata'), (float(input('Qual o preço da batata? R$ ')))),
    (('Cenoura'), (float(input('Qual o preço da cenoura? R$ ')))),
    (('Vagem'), (float(input('Qual o preço da vagem? R$ '))))
]

menor_valor_da_lista = min(lista_de_compras[0][1], lista_de_compras[1][1], lista_de_compras[2][1])

print(f'Você deve levar a **___** que custa R${menor_valor_da_lista}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Escolha a estrutura de dados adequada

Você criou uma lista de tuplas, mas se a ideia é mapear cada produto com o seu respectivo preço, um dicionário me parece mais adequado.

Não só faz mais sentido para esse caso, como também facilitará muito a solução. Ficaria assim:

```
lista_de_compras = {}
for produto in ['batata', 'cenoura', 'vagem']:
    lista_de_compras[produto] = float(input(f'preço de {produto}, R$ '))

mais_barato = min(lista_de_compras, key=lista_de_compras.get)

print(f'Você deve levar {mais_barato} que custa R${lista_de_compras[mais_barato]:.2f}')
```

Para imprimir o preço, usei as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), para imprimir sempre com duas casas decimais.

Ao usar [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), eu indico que quero usar `lista_de_compras.get`, o que faz com que sejam comparados os preços em vez dos nomes. O resultado é o produto que tem o menor preço, e aí basta imprimi-lo.

Só que isso não resolve os casos de empate, quando mais de um produto for o mais barato. Nesse caso, bastaria percorrer o dicionário e imprimir todos que tem o mesmo preço:

```
mais_barato = min(lista_de_compras, key=lista_de_compras.get)

menor_preco = lista_de_compras[mais_barato]

print(f'produtos mais baratos, custam R${menor_preco:.2f}')
for produto, preco in lista_de_compras.items():
    if preco == menor_preco:
        print(produto)
```

---

A menos que você já receba a lista de tuplas daquela maneira, não há motivo para usá-la, pois um dicionário faz muito mais sentido para esse caso. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458416/112052) até mostra que dá para resolver com a lista, mas fica desnecessariamente mais complicado, e tudo porque não é a estrutura de dados mais adequada para resolver o problema.

Escolher a estrutura de dados adequada [é meio caminho andado para um código melhor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163185).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizando a função `map` obter uma nova lista contendo os preços de cada produto. Basta passar no primeiro parâmetro uma função receba um item (tupla) e retorne o segundo elemento deste item (preço). Veja o código abaixo:

```
valores = list(map(lambda item: item[1], lista_de_compras))
```

Como você é iniciante e talvez o código acima ainda é um pouquinho avançado para você, aqui está um outro código que é equivalente, porém um pouquinho maior.

```
def obter_valores(lista):
    valores = []

    for item in lista:
        valores.append(item[1])
        
    return valores
```

Depois de ter obtido todos os valores precisamos saber qual o menor valor da lista certo? Para isso, podemos utilizar a função `min` que retorna o menor valor de um iterável.

```
min([5, 7, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4])  # Retorna o valor 2
```

Como o objetivo é obter o item por completo (tupla), podemos utilizar o método `index` da lista de valores para obter o índice do valor, índice este que será o mesmo do item na lista de compras.

```
indice_do_menor_valor = valores.index(min(valores))
```

Agora basta apenas obter o item através desse índice e pronto. Abaixo está o código completo:

```
valores = list(map(lambda item: item[1], lista_de_compras))
indice_do_menor_valor = valores.index(min(valores))

nome, valor = lista_de_compras[indice_do_menor_valor]
print(f'Você deve levar a {nome} que custa R${valor}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizaria um dicionário ao invés de uma tupla e deixaria o código assim:

```
lista_de_compras = {
    ('Batata'): (float(input('Qual o preço da batata? R$ '))),
    ('Cenoura'): (float(input('Qual o preço da cenoura? R$ '))),
    ('Vagem'): (float(input('Qual o preço da vagem? R$ ')))
}

menor_valor_da_lista = min(lista_de_compras, key=lista_de_compras.get)

print(f'Você deve levar a {menor_valor_da_lista} que custa R${lista_de_compras[menor_valor_da_lista]}')
```